# if statement not working properly in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

i want to redirect button in questions page except for last page ,so i used this code

views.py

```
def question_detail(request,question_id,quiz_id):
q = Quiz.objects.get(pk=quiz_id)
que = q.question_set.get(pk=question_id)
ans = que.answer_set.all()
count = q.question_set.count()
come = que.rank
came = come + 1
later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=came)
return render(request, 'app/question_detail.html', {'que': que, 'later_question': later_question, 'ans': ans, 'count':count})
```

question_detail.html

```
{% if later_question > count %}
    <button><a href="{% url 'app:detail' quiz_id=que.quiz.id question_id=later_question.id%}">Question {{later_question.rank}}</a></button>
{% else %}
    <button><a href="">result</a></button>
{% endif %}
```

this code showing result button on every page

Comment: `count` is an integer, whereas `later_question` is a `question`. How would you compare the two?

Comment: thanks, this very silly mistake that i have done
{% later_question.rank > count %}